# Como usar o operador "when" do LESS?

Tags: operadores, less, when

Dei uma rápida procurada no site do less para ver como se utiliza, mas não obtive sucesso, então queria saber como funciona o operador **when** do LESS!?

**Exemplos:**

```css
box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
}

.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
  .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
```

Como ele funciona?

(Opcional) Se souber onde fica a documentação de operadores como o *when* no LESS, poderia me informar? Agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome desse recurso é [*guarded mixins*](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature), e serve para testar expressões, semelhante às estruturas condicionais existentes em várias linguagens. Porém, ao invés de `if/else`, o less faz isso com a palavra chave [`when`](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature).

Pegando o exemplo da sua pergunta:

```less
.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)){
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
          box-shadow: @style @c;
}

.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
   .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
```

Existem duas formas de chamar `.box-shadow()` e dependendo do tipo de parâmetro, a regra será compilada de uma forma diferente.

Se o retorno da função [`iscolor()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-iscolor) for `true`, a primeira regra será compilada. Do contrário, o *mixin* será ignorado. No entanto como existe outro *mixin* com o mesmo nome, ele será testado também e se o retorno de [`isnumber()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-isnumber) for verdadeiro, este será compilado. Se ambas as condições forem falsas, a regra será descartada.

```less
/* foo.less */
.meu-elemento {
    .box-shadow(0 0 10px, red);
}

/* foo.css */
.meu-elemento {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```less
/* foo.less */
.meu-elemento {
  .box-shadow(0 0 1px, 25%);
}

/* foo.css */
.meu-elemento {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Exemplos de *mixins* ignorados:

```less
.meu-elemento {
  .box-shadow(0 0 1px, "numero?"); /* tipo: string */
}

.meu-elemento {
  .box-shadow(0 0 1px, url('foo/img.png')); /* tipo: url */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O when funciona como um if o mixin so será executado se a condição for verdadeira.

> box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c))

O mixin so será executado se o parâmetro @c for uma cor.

http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature

Comment: Exatamente, e ele funciona como loop. Mesmo depois do seu css ser interpretado, se a condição dentro de when virar verdadeira em algum momento, então ele chamará a mixin que estiver definida para ele